# Comment and uncomment css code with vmap in Vim

Tags: vim

I try to comment and uncomment css file with vmap

when I select lines in css file and comment them out with 'xx'

```
autocmd BufEnter *.css vmap  xx  :s/\%V\s*\(\S.*$\)\%V/\/* \1 *\//g <CR>
```

It works perfectly

But when I try to vmap 'xu' to uncomment the css code,

```
autocmd BufEnter *.css vmap  xu  :s/\%V\/\*\|**\/\%V//g <CR>


'xx' comment =>   background-color => /*  background-color:red;  */
'xu' uncomment =>  /*  background-color */ => background-color
```

The mapping is try to remove `'/*' and '*/'` from my selected lines in css file.

I got following error:

```
E871: (NFA regexp) Can't have a multi follow a multi !
E61: Nested *
E476: Invalid command
```

It seems to me I CAN NOT have 'or' operator between '\%V and \%V' which is visual block in Vim.

Anyone know how to solve the problem

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with those two asterisks?

Comment: If you try to remove '/*' and '*/' from css file, you need the regex (two asterisks) to match them, Do't ask me why since I have no idea how Regex engine implementation work

Comment: That `**` is the cause of your issue. It means "any number of the previous atom any number of the previous atom" which is pointless. If you want to match "any number of `*`", you need to escape the first `*`: `\**`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem

If you check your mapping, you'll see that it's not defined as expected:

```
:vmap xu
v  xu            :s/\%V\/\*|**\/\%V//g <CR>
```

Inside a mapping, the `|` command separator would end the mapping command, and therefore needs to be escaped. (Cp. [`:help map-bar`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map-bar)). This usually is done via `<Bar>`, but can also be done by prepending a `\`. Accidentally, your regular expression had just this, thereby avoided the mapping definition error, but also corrupted the mapping.

```
vmap  xu  :s/\%V\/\*\<Bar>**\/\%V//g <CR>
```

You probably should also consistently escape the second literal `*`; this would have given you a different (*pattern not found*) error instead of the E871:

```
vmap  xu  :s/\%V\/\*\<Bar>\**\/\%V//g <CR>
```

#### The autocmd

... works, but isn't how it's usually done. Vim has *filetype detection*, and out of the box detects `*.css` as `filetype=css` for you. There's no need to duplicate that information into your autocmd. Instead, you can hook into the `FileType` event:

```
autocmd FileType css vmap  xu  :s/\%V\/\*\<Bar>\**\/\%V//g <CR>
```

#### Alternative to autocmds

I would recommend putting any settings, mappings, and filetype-specific autocmds into `~/.vim/ftplugin/{filetype}_whatever.vim` (or `{filetype}/whatever.vim`; cp. `:help ftplugin-name`) instead of defining lots of `:autocmd FileType {filetype}`; it's cleaner and scales better; requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`, though. Settings that *override* stuff in default filetype plugins should go into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim` instead.

#### More small fixes

- [You should use `:vnoremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) instead of `:vmap`; it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- After editing a CSS file, the mapping will also be active in any other buffer, because it is a *global* one. Add the `<buffer>` argument to limit it to the (CSS) buffer.
- You can use another separator for `:substitute`; it avoids the escaping of the `/` in the pattern and makes this a bit more readable.

#### Final recommendation

I would put the following into `~/.vim/ftplugin/css_mappings.vim`:

```
vnoremap <buffer> xu :s#\%V/\*\<Bar>\**/\%V##g <CR>
```

#### Or use a plugin

(Unless you're a minimalist that avoids plugins at some cost, or if you've done this only for the learning experience.)

Please note that there are several commenter plugins that do this very well, and those are generic (and often extensible) so that they work for any filetype:

- [NERD Commenter plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218)
- [tComment plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173)
- [commentary.vim plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3695)

Comment: thanks, ingo, you always have the answer for my vim problem:)

Comment: I try to avoid to use plugin right now, since I installed many plugins before and my Vim ran very slow and I had to remove them all since I have no way to figure which plugin to cause the vim so slowness. I just write everything by hand and I know what I should if I have issue with my Vim.

Comment: It's a tradeoff between reinventing the wheel (often poorly) and bloating the system with too many plugins. It's not the sheer number of plugins; it heavily depends on what they do. Especially many `:autocmd`s on frequent events can drag down performance. A small plugin script, with heavy use of autoload scripts, gets bonus points for a quick startup. For those commenter plugins, they mostly just define a couple of mappings, so it should be fine.